Link invariants on a thickened surface
Let $\Sigma$ be an oriented surface. I want to know about link invariants in $\Sigma\times [0,1]$. I already know the Ozawa polynomial introduced in this paper, but I couldn’t find any other than that. Also I want to know open problems about
them.
Any comments are welcome.

If you are interested in invariants that are preserved under stabilization & destabilization of $\Sigma$, then Carter, Kamada and Saito showed these are exactly the same thing as "virtual link invariants."  See https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0008118

Kuperberg furthermore showed that "virtual links" are exactly the same thing as links on thickened surfaces that are irreducible with respect to destabilizing.  See https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208039
